# When I configure SSL on nginx the website stops working for port 80

Tags: nginx

I have a basic HTML/CSS/jQuery APP. It is running on NGINX.

When I set up a SSL for my website, it does not work for port 80.

The website is dailystockstats.com

the nginx configuration is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

   server_name www.dailystockstats.com dailystockstats.com;


    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/connectingdots.science.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/connectingdots.science.key;

    root /var/www/dailystockstats/;
    #include /var/www/dailystockstats/nginx.conf;

}
```

Comment: By "it does not work" - what do you mean? Do you get connection reset on the port 80? Does nginx fail to start? What behavior are you expecting? What happens instead?

Comment: http://dailystockstats.com/ is going to GoDadday Parking Page.